# Path to Windows 8/10 app from win 7/xna/monogame/xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xna

I've made an [educational game](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=fd8dbe7a-8320-4465-b739-4ac9d5ddfd74) for Windows Phone 7 with XNA - which is now a dead technology. But through MonoGame and Xamarin I have been able to port it to Android. Now I need it as an app for Windows tablets, windows 8 app or windows 10 universal app.

What is the best route to this? I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with Xamarin Business edition. And I don't know enough about my options. Should I start with the XNA version or the Android/Xamarin version? What template or architecture is best. Or do I need to do a complete rewrite (only keeping the C# business logic)?

Comment: I also have to do this soon.  My code is divided between a C# core that I can re-use, and a Xamarin Android GUI part, that I can't.  I was thinking of starting a new solution in Visual studio, copy in my core business logic part, and re-make the GUI (OK, I will probably use that as a base for the Windows app GUI, like old fashioned porting).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to reuse the UI code also - at least to some degree?

Comment: That depends on how you've made your UI. Since it's an XNA game, it's likely you've made your own UI using sprite drawing. In that case, it's pretty easy. Just replace whatever classes handles the "Touch"ing on buttons. If you've used native controls, no, there's no easy way to do it, and you'll be best off redoing the UI from scratch on whatever platform you're developing for.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I use sprite drawing.

Comment: MonoGame claims that it supports Windows Store apps.

Comment: Great, but which project template should I use in Visual Studio (with Xamarin) for a MonoGame Windows store app?